# Datatables ordering and responsive.recalc() freeze my browser

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've a modal with a datatable inside.

This is the thead:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
<th data-priority="1" class="noVis"></th>
        <th data-priority="1" class="text-center azioni colCheckbox noVis"><input value="1" type="checkbox" /></th>
        <th data-priority="1" class="noVis">Anteprima</th>
        <th data-priority="1" class="noVis">Nome</th>
        <th data-priority="1">---</th>
        <th data-priority="3">---</th>
        <th data-priority="3">---</th>
        <th data-priority="4">---</th>
        <th data-priority="5">---</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
```

It is responsive and selectable with:

```
"aaSorting": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
   responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column',
            target: 0
        }
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'control',
            searchable: false,
            targets:   0
        },
        {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'selectall-checkbox',
            searchable: false,
            targets:   1
        }
    ],
select: {
        style:    'multi',
        selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
    },
```

Initial ordering is by NAME column by ASC

[image]

After I click order for NAME column for a DESC ordering, i get problem cause responsive doesn't appear (i've some cell NAME empty so all columns stay in the view for ASC order, but i've also a cell NAME with long values so if I click for a DESC order i get this problem)

[image]

But if I init datatables with DESC order all is ok cause responsive is initialized!

I tried to insert this code (global for all tables):

```
$(document).on('order.dt', function () {

   $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust().responsive.recalc().draw();

} );
```

but browser (firefox get freeze ). I get error log: "too much recursion"

How can i force datatable to check responsive after a order column?

UPDATED: My fiddle http://live.datatables.net/xiyozede/2/edit

Comment: I've update the fiddle to see the problem: http://live.datatables.net/xiyozede/2/edit

Comment: did you see that when you scroll data after sorting, column is not moving with data.

Comment: if you update jsbin, please mention in your question.